# Why does my docker-compose app fail on first run and work on the second try?

Tags: mysql, spring-boot, docker, docker-compose, deployment

I have want to dockerize a spring boot application with mysql database using docker compose and it fails on first run and works on second and i would like to find an explainnation. I suppose on the first run, it creates the database or something and the spring boot app fails because something is not initialized properly but i am not sure. How can i solve this?

```
version: '5'
services:
  mysql:
    image: mysql:latest
    ports:
      - "3307:3306"
    environment:
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: root
      MYSQL_DATABASE: rentalapp
    command: mysqld --sql_mode=""
    volumes:
      - ./my.cnf:/etc/mysql/my.cnf
    container_name: mysqlimage1

  app:
    image: crudimage:crudapp
    ports:
      - "8090:8080"
    environment:
      SPRING_JPA_GENERATE_DDL: true
      SPRING_JPA_HIBERNATE_DDL_AUTO: update
      SPRING_JPA_DATABASE_PLATFORM: org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect
      SPRING_JPA_SHOW_SQL: true
      SPRING_DATASOURCE_URL: jdbc:mysql://mysql:3306/rentalapp
      SPRING_DATASOURCE_USERNAME: root
      SPRING_DATASOURCE_PASSWORD: root
      SERVER_ERROR_INCLUDE_MESSAGE: always
    depends_on:
      - mysql
    container_name: crudappimage1
```

```
FROM openjdk:17

COPY target/crudapp.jar .

EXPOSE 8080

ENTRYPOINT ["java", "-jar", "crudapp.jar"]
```

```
spring.jpa.generate-ddl=true
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=update
spring.jpa.database-platform= org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect
spring.jpa.show-sql=true
spring.datasource.url= jdbc:mysql://${MYSQL_HOST:localhost}:${MYSQL_PORT:3306}/${MYSQL_DB_NAME:rentalapp}
spring.datasource.username= ${MYSQL_USER:root}
spring.datasource.password= ${MYSQL_PASSWORD:root}

server.error.include-message=always
```

Comment: Please edit your post and include any error messages you get

Comment: How exactly does it fail?  If you're getting something like a "connection refused" error talking to the database, that can happen if the application starts up before the database initialization is finished; if you run `docker-compose up` without a `-d` option you'll also see more database log messages after the application exits.  [Docker Compose wait for container X before starting Y](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31746182/docker-compose-wait-for-container-x-before-starting-y) discusses this situation further.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on docker compose file i can guess/say that the problem is very popular one:
In your config docker compose run `mysql` first and after it the `application`. Here application start faster than `mysql` will be ready to have connections.

To fix it add one more param on
application part in docker compose file:

```
app:
    image: crudimage:crudapp
    ports:
      - "8090:8080"
    environment:
      SPRING_JPA_GENERATE_DDL: true
      SPRING_JPA_HIBERNATE_DDL_AUTO: update
      SPRING_JPA_DATABASE_PLATFORM: org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect
      SPRING_JPA_SHOW_SQL: true
      SPRING_DATASOURCE_URL: jdbc:mysql://mysql:3306/rentalapp
      SPRING_DATASOURCE_USERNAME: root
      SPRING_DATASOURCE_PASSWORD: root
      SERVER_ERROR_INCLUDE_MESSAGE: always
    depends_on:
      - mysql
         condition: service_completed_successfully
    container_name: crudappimage1
```

What does it mean ?
`service_completed_successfully` - specifies that a dependency is expected to run to successful completion before starting a dependent service.